# How to properly position item inside grid system?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Actually I have a layout build with one row class and two column by using bootstrap grid system.

Now I need to add another one item inside that grid system but I'm unable to position it properly inside the layout as it's going under all other columns.
As you can see on the screenshot 
 [image: screenshot]

As you can see the third column I'm trying to add goes under all other while I would to place it in the red rectangle position

The layout is build as the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 mt-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8 mb-4 mt-1"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I was trying to add something like that to put the 3rd column but the result was as described above

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 mt-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8 mb-4 mt-1"></div>
      <div class="col align-self-start"><div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the following approach

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- There will be column with 2 right box  -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 mb-4 mt-1">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    ITEM UNDER 1ST BOX
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- This will be your larger left box -->
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 mt-1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```